# How to configure navigation stack?

Tags: ros, navigation, range

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that there should be many tutorials about this but i can't find anything.
I've just set publishers and subscribers for sensors stuff, odometry stuff and IMU. Now, how can i set everything to notice navigation stack the creation of this stuff? what configuration files should i create? and where?
Thank you!
ps: My sensors are sonar, i published a Range message, i've read that it is possible to integrate this in navigation stack, but how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239703/how-to-configure-navigation-stack?/) by [Oper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27436/oper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here you go

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2016-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1